# Problema (App en blanco) y error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy probando a hacer un RecyclerView y aunque aparentemente el Build dice que todo está correcto, luego cuando se abre la app sale todo el RecyclerView en blanco (solo se ve el Toolbar). He probado a meterme en el Run y he encontrado el siguiente error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

He estado leyendo muchas preguntas de compañeros y por lo visto el error es bastante común, pero yo no he conseguido identificar en mi código el fallo.

Mi MainActivity es el siguiente:

```
package com.vidamrr.ejemplorecyclerview

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var lista:RecyclerView? = null
    var adaptador:AdaptadorCustom? = null
    var layoutManager:RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val platillos = ArrayList<Platillo>()

        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 1", 250.0, 3.5, R.drawable.comida1))
        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 2", 470.0, 1.5, R.drawable.comida2))
        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 3", 300.8, 4.5, R.drawable.comida3))
        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 4",435.5 , 5.0, R.drawable.comida4))
        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 5", 100.8, 2.0, R.drawable.comida5))
        platillos.add(Platillo("Platillo 6", 470.0, 1.5, R.drawable.comida6))

        lista = findViewById(R.id.lista)
        lista?.setHasFixedSize(true)

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        lista?.layoutManager = layoutManager

        lista?.adapter = adaptador

        adaptador = AdaptadorCustom(platillos, object:ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, platillos.get(index).nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }, object:LongClickListener {
            override fun longClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
                Log.d("LONG", "Prueba")
            }
        })


        val swipeToRefresh = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
        swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            for(i in 1..1000000000){

            }
            swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
            platillos.add(Platillo("Nuggets", 470.0, 1.5, R.drawable.comida1))
            adaptador?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }
}
```

El AdaptadorCustom es:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.RatingBar
import android.widget.TextView
import org.w3c.dom.Text
import java.util.ArrayList
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode
import android.util.Log

class AdaptadorCustom(items:ArrayList<Platillo>, var listener:ClickListener, var longClickListener: LongClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCustom.ViewHolder>() {

    var items: ArrayList<Platillo>? = null

    init {
        this.items = items
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdaptadorCustom.ViewHolder {
        val vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.template_platillo,parent, false)
        val viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista, listener, longClickListener)

        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items?.count()!!


    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = items?.get(position)
        holder.foto?.setImageResource(item?.foto!!)
        holder.nombre?.text = item?.nombre
        holder.precio?.text = "$" + item?.precio.toString()
        holder.rating?.rating = item?.rating?.toFloat()!!



    }

    class ViewHolder(vista:View, listener:ClickListener, longClickListener: LongClickListener): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{



        var vista = vista
        var foto: ImageView? = null
        var nombre: TextView? = null
        var precio: TextView? = null
        var rating: RatingBar? = null
        var listener:ClickListener? = null
        var longListener:LongClickListener? = null

        init{
            foto = vista.findViewById(R.id.ivfoto)
            nombre = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvnombre)
            precio = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvprecio)
            rating = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvrating)
            this.listener = listener
            this.longListener = longClickListener
            vista.setOnClickListener(this)
            vista.setOnLongClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            this.listener?.onClick(v!!, adapterPosition)
        }

        override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
            this.longListener?.longClick(v!!, adapterPosition)

            return true
        }

    }
```

Y luego tengo una interface que es "ClickListener":

```
package com.vidamrr.ejemplorecyclerview

import android.view.View

interface ClickListener {

    fun onClick(vista:View, index:Int)


}
```

Y otra interface que es LongClickListener:

```
package com.vidamrr.ejemplorecyclerview

import android.view.View

interface LongClickListener {

    fun longClick(vista: View, index:Int)

}
```

La cosa es que cuando he implementado ClickListener todo ha ido bien, se veía todo perfecto. El fallo o error ha comenzado al escribir el código correspondiente a LongClickListener.

Muchas gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo, 
Álvaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es sencillo, estas asignando el adaptador antes de crearlo, por lo que siempre asignas un adaptador nulo.

En vez de hacer esto:

```
lista?.adapter = adaptador

adaptador = AdaptadorCustom(platillos, object:ClickListener {
    override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, platillos.get(index).nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}, object:LongClickListener {
    override fun longClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
        Log.d("LONG", "Prueba")
    }
})
```

Tienes que hacer esto:

```
adaptador = AdaptadorCustom(platillos, object:ClickListener {
    override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, platillos.get(index).nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}, object:LongClickListener {
    override fun longClick(vista: View, index: Int) {
        Log.d("LONG", "Prueba")
    }
})

lista?.adapter = adaptador
```

Simplemente declara el adaptador antes de asignarlo al RecyclerView.